# Query More Than 100 DynamoDB Items that match a Partition Key using Java SDK 2?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-java-sdk-2.x, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

**How can more than 100 items from a dynamodb table, matching a particular partition key, be queried using aws java sdk 2?**

If the number of rows that match a hash key [exceeds 100 then the batchGetItemPaginator method](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbClient.html#batchGetItemPaginator-software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.BatchGetItemRequest-) needs to be used.  This method accepts a [`BatchGetItemRequest`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/model/BatchGetItemRequest.html) which requires a [`KeysAndAttributes`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/model/KeysAndAttributes.Builder.html#keys-java.util.Collection-).

When I construct a KeysAndAttributes with just a hash key, but not a sort key, I get the following exception

> DynamoDbException: The provided key element does not match the schema

However, if I provide a sort key in the KeysAndAttributes then the batchGetItemPaginator method works fine.

So how can a BatchGetItemRequest be constructed with **just** a primary key (no sort key)?

Note: my question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30969594/query-all-items-in-dynamodb-from-a-given-hash-key-with-a-hash-range-schema-using).  That other question does not involve the required pagination if the number of rows exceeds 100.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primary key >> Partition + HashKey

[GetItem](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/dynamodb/get-item.html) is used to get one item by primary key.

[BatchGetItem](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/dynamodb/batch-get-item.html) is used to get multiple items from multiple tables using multiple primary keys. so, we need to pass list of Partition & HashKey

We can never do a getItem or batchGetItem with partial key i.e just Partition Key.

To fetch items just by partition key, we must use [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html) api, which returns maximum of 1 MB of data. To fetch all the records with a particular partition key, we can paginate by calling query api multiple times with exclusiveStartKey

`.exclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey)` helps us to start after a particular record.

`.limit(10)` usually set to a reasonable number that doesn't exceed total size beyond 1 MB. if no of items is not a concern, we can exclude this.

`response.lastEvaluatedKey()` capture this from the response to be used for next query.

```
public static Map<String, AttributeValue> queryTable(DynamoDbClient ddb, String tableName, String partitionKeyName,
        String partitionKeyVal, Map<String, AttributeValue> exclusiveStartKey) {

    Map<String, AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey = null;

    HashMap<String, AttributeValue> attrValues = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
    attrValues.put(":" + partitionKeyName, AttributeValue.builder().s(partitionKeyVal).build());
    QueryRequest queryReq = QueryRequest.builder().tableName(tableName).exclusiveStartKey(exclusiveStartKey)
            .keyConditionExpression(partitionKeyName + " = :" + partitionKeyName)
            .expressionAttributeValues(attrValues).limit(10).build();

    try {
        QueryResponse response = ddb.query(queryReq);
        lastEvaluatedKey = response.lastEvaluatedKey();
    } catch (DynamoDbException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    return lastEvaluatedKey;
}
```

sample test on table `test` with `pk` as partition key for value `1`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
    DynamoDbClient ddb = DynamoDbClient.builder().region(region).build();

    Map<String, AttributeValue> lastEvaluatedKey = null;
    // Loop until we don't get lastEvaluatedKey 
    do {
        System.out.println("---------DynamoDb Query with Exclusive Start Key------------" + lastEvaluatedKey);
        lastEvaluatedKey = queryTable(ddb, "test", "pk", "1", lastEvaluatedKey);
    } while (lastEvaluatedKey != null && !lastEvaluatedKey.isEmpty());

    ddb.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response!  The clarification between `query` and `BatchGetItem` is very helpful.  However, the documentation for query states that the response is at most 1 MB.  Could you please update your example to including pagination?

Comment: @RamónJRomeroyVigil Updated Answer with paginated query example

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer above is partially wrong (at least as of v2 of the Java SDK), you can do a batch get item with only a primary key.

Unfortunately, the code I have is proprietary therefore I can't share it but just look at the Javadocs around batch get item.

For example: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/model/BatchGetItemResponse.html